# How to render a sitemap XML file in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, sitemap

Is there an already implemented mechanism to create a (HTML) sitemap from an XML file?

I'm using a [`Python` script](http://sitemap-generators.googlecode.com/) to generate sitemaps and want to gisplay (a part of) my sitemap as HTML list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with simple_xml:

```php
$xmlFile = 'sitemap.xml';

if (!file_exists($xmlFile)) {
    throw new \Exception("File does not exist");
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

echo "<ul class=\"sitemap\">";
foreach($xml as $url) {
    echo "<li>" . $url->loc . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This snippet creates a shallow list. What I meaned is a nested list, in order to display it on the site.

Comment: Well give an example of the XML. It will be easy to adapt :)

Comment: That's not how I would do it but I will accept edit if it works for you. I think it would make more sense to create a recursive function.

Comment: You are right, it's not the best way, and even not a clean one. A recursive function would be a good solution. Another possibility would be to write an XSL stylesheet.